# TortoiseSVN vs Command Prompt svn switch error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

I'm trying to switch my WC between releases (and/or trunk), and can easily do it if I

```
Right-click > TortoiseSVN > "Switch..."
```

inside the WC directory, but if I try to run `svn switch` from cmd, I get an error that I'm trying to switch into a different repository:

```
C:\svn\EGS>svn switch file:///c:/repositories/repo2/releases/r2019
svn: E155025: 'svn switch' does not support switching a working copy to a different repository
svn: E155025: 'file:///C:/Repositories/repo2/trunk'
is not the same repository as
'file:///C:/repositories/repo2'
```

where `C:\svn\EGS>` is currently a WC for `file:///c:/repositories/repo2/trunk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that subversion repositories are case-sensitive, particularly when you're using URLs. While yes, when you're navigating through Windows Explorer or the cmd line, Windows can handle it, but svn needs to be compatible with **case-sensitive** file systems such as Linux/Unix and MacOS for example  as compared to Windows's **case-*insensitive*** file system. Therefore, it's better to get into the habit of keeping your naming conventions in your repository consistent for both your directory structure and your svn commands/scripts.

To resolve your issue, you just need to update your command to:

```
svn switch file:///C:/Repositories/repo2/releases/r2019
```